# Autohotkey NumpadMult not sending *

Tags: autohotkey, numpad

I have the following snippet of code in my ahk script, which should send NumpadMult when semicolon is pressed, however it just sends a semicolon:

```
;::
    Send, {NumpadMult}
    return
```

I have similar code for period to NumpadDot, and all other Numpad keys, which work fine. Below is a picture of semicolon and period being pressed, and the resultant key history.

[image: Column labels L->R VK code, SC code, Type, Up/Dn, Elapsed Time, Key]

What could be the issue? Maybe the compiler is getting confused since semicolon is also used for comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

You need to add a ` before the semicolon. I'm assuming this escapes the comment function.

The code is now:

```
`;::
    Send, {NumpadMult}
    return
```